# Open popup after a certain interval and close on click anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to open my popup box after a certain interval like(5000) and close it by click on the anchor tag that I made in popup box.

```
function call() {
    $('.popup-box').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.popup').css({ 'transform': 'scale(1, 1)' });
        $('body').css({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })
    });
}

function close() {
    $('a.hider').on('click', function() {
        $('.popup').css({ 'transform': 'scale(0, 0)' });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.popup-box').fadeOut(500);
            $('body').css({ 'overflow-y': 'scroll' });
        }, 300);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Did you ever heard about .delay() method in jquery? if you didn't aware of that please check it is useful for your context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.delay()` method in jquery for set time interval delay

```
function call() {
    $('.popup-box').delay(5000).fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.popup').css({ 'transform': 'scale(1, 1)' });
        $('body').css({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry Sir I am new to all this but getting this much of help from you is really appreciable.